# Density function approximation with respect to $L^1$ distance

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics

Given iid samples $X_1,...,X_N$ drawn from some unknown distribution with not necessarily continuous density function $f(x)$ are there any theorems/papers where based on the data $X_1,...,X_N$ an estimator $f_N(x)$ of $f(x)$  is defined and the approximation rate
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)-f_N(x)|dx$$
is estimated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [description](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471816469) of the book *Nonparametric Density Estimation: The L1 View* by Devroye and Gyorfi:

> The first systematic single-source examination of density estimates. It develops, from first principles, the ``natural'' theory for density estimation, L1, and shows why the classical L2 theory masks some fundamental properties of density estimates.